# Igraph no such attribute error when trying to read external file

Tags: python, igraph

I am on Windows 10 and managed to download the python-igraph package with no problem. I put it under the folder of site-packages in anaconda under the name igraph. I then tried to import an edgelist but it returned with the error of module igraph has no attribute Read.Edgelist. The code is below:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import uniform, seed
import numpy as np
import time
from igraph import *
g = Graph.Read_Edgelist("C:/facebook_combined.txt")
```

I'm using this guy's code from this blog here: https://hautahi.com/im_greedycelf. Is it possible that igraph is no longer able to read external files? I'm very confused.

Even trying to create a simple graph also yielded an error message:

```
import igraph
g = Graph.Tree(127, 2)
summary(g)
Error: name 'Graph' is not defined
```

Am I doing something wrong? If so, can someone put a link to the required libraries I have to download and tell me which folder to put it under? I'm not really sure how the installers they mentioned on here: https://pypi.org/project/python-igraph/ work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first snippet didn't work because `Read_Edgelist` is an instance method. 
So you need to create an object first and then call the `Read_Edgelist` function on that.

For example

```
g = Graph()
g.Read_Edgelist("C:/facebook_combined.txt")
```

---

Your second snippet didn't work because your import statement is `import igraph`

Then you must use

```py
g = igraph.Graph.Tree(127,2(
summary(g)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, the code still didn't work. The error for the first snippet reads "module" object is not callable, while the second is module 'igraph' has no attribute 'Graph'. I'm beginning to suspect I installed igraph wrongly. If possible, can you walk me through how to install igraph on windows properly? The website is very vague and I didn't find it very helpful. Thanks in advance.